# Creat and access dictionary within class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I have created a class within `tkinter` that builds a frame and buttons (example below).

I am also trying to create a series of radiobuttons each with a command, and rather than having to type three times the same, I am trying to use a dictionary that stores the function name and the function (again see below):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class EnoxDoseCalculator:    
    def __init__(self, root):
       root.title('Enoxaparin Dose Calculator')
       indication = {'VTE': self.vte,  'Atrial Fibrilation': self.af, 'Mechanical Heart valve': self.mech}
    
       mainframe = ttk.Frame(root)
       mainframe.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky='nsew')
       test_button = ttk.Button(mainframe, text= 'Push Mew!!', command = self.format)
       test_button.grid(row = 0, column = 0)

   def vte(self):
       pass

   def af(self):
       pass
       
   def mech(self):
       pass

   def format(self):
       self.var3 = tk.StringVar()
       for key, value in self.indication.items():
           ttk.Radiobutton(mainframe, text = self.indication.key, variable = self.var3, value = self.indication.key, command = self.indication.value).grid(row = n+1, column =0, sticky = 'nswe')

root = Tk()
EnoxDoseCalculator(root)
print(dir(EnoxDoseCalculator))

root.mainloop()
```

However, I keep getting this message:
I get this is to do with the dictionary functions being listed before they are created, so my question is, where do I place said dictionary, because I am sure this is possible. or is it that I am using the wrong names for the function?

Comment: ok, so do I need to add them to the __init__ as self.vte = vte? And does it matter that there is a function (method) called vte?

Comment: Well, the symptom sounds like it is caused by an indentation problem. How is the line: `indication = {'VTE' ... ` indented?

Comment: I have placed it below the __init__ method

Comment: I can see which line it is on, but what about its indentation? You should review all of your posted code for indentation to make sure what we see here is what you have in your development environment.

Comment: I think you need do indent the lines below `indication` and before `def vte()` so they are included in `__init__()` as well

Comment: Like it is now?

Comment: Ok, I see you have updated your code. Do you still get the same error you originally posted, or has that changed as well?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/alejandro/Dropbox/python/test.py", line 49, in format
    for key, value in self.indication.items():
AttributeError: 'EnoxDoseCalculator' object has no attribute 'indication'
when I run the function 'format'

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: You need to change local variables to instance variables (prefix `self.`) inside `__init__()` if you want to access them inside other class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class EnoxDoseCalculator:    
    def __init__(self, root):
       self.root = root  # add this (mostly for consistency/best practice)
       self.root.title('Enoxaparin Dose Calculator')
       self.indication = {'VTE': self.vte,  'Atrial Fibrilation': self.af, 'Mechanical Heart valve': self.mech}
    
       self.mainframe = ttk.Frame(self.root)  # update this to include 'self'
       self.mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')
       # update this to include 'self'
       self.test_button = ttk.Button(self.mainframe, text='Push Mew!!', command=self.format)
       self.test_button.grid(row=0, column=0)
```

Using `self` to namespace your class variables to `EnoxDoseCalculator`

Comment: Works! Thanks a lot, just learning my way through OOP Tkinter.
Much appreciated.

Comment: Happy to help! Understanding OOP is going to be a huge asset for GUI programming - good luck to you!